# Running the same Rails code on multiple laptops and saving the data from all of them to the same Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to run the same rails code on multiple laptops on localhost:3000. How can I save the data submitted from the different laptops to save in a single database. Or, they would share the same database and if someone has submitted data, it would automatically be on the other persons laptop. Also consider that there won't be any internet connection, but we can connect them with Ethernet cables. Also, we are using sqllite3 . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you would like to use mysql in that case - it is designed to work this way, you just specify remote host instead of 'localhost' in config.
However, you can put sqlite database in ftp/sftp/webdav server, mount as local folder (kinda complicated on windows tho), and try to use it, which will work REALLY slow.

Comment: do you know how to connect a mysql database to rails?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html (3.15.2 connecting to mysql database)
would be something like that
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: 192.168.1.0